# Smarty Templates - Multiple Classes

Tags: smarty

Here is my template code:

```
<li class="{$product.name}" {if $product.name == $filter_product.name}class=active{/if}">
```

I want to be able to set the `$product.name` as the class, and when the `$product.name` is the active filter also add the class `"active"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
{if $product.name == $filter_product.name}
  <li class="active {$product.name}">
{else}
  <li class="{$product.name}">
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one class attribute, but it can contain more than one class - separate them using a space. So in your example:

```
<li class="{$product.name}{if $product.name == $filter_product.name} active{/if}">
```

Comment: Smarty only outputs the first $product.name class.